# Touchupinside and simple viewController question

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I've got a very simple viewController question .

I've got a main view with 2 buttons, upon touchupinside of a button I would like to load a new view Controller ( a table view ) .

I've created a new viewController with its nib file .

Created an IBAction like this that I've linked the button to in IB :

```
- (IBAction)displayVin {

    UIViewController *vinController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"vinController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vinController animated:YES];
    [vinController release];

}
```

It's not doing anything therefore I must be forgetting something, but what ? should I declare this newViewController somewhere else ? It's compiling and executing fine with no error message .

**UPDATE:**

I'm now using this :

```
- (IBAction)displayVin:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"here");
    UIViewController *vinController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"vinController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vinController animated:YES];
    [vinController release];

}
```

But it's crashing with this error when I press the button :

*[displayVin]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d03000
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[displayVin]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d03000'*

Should I be declaring something somewhere else , or "should" that bit of code be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Start by using NSLog() to determine if you're actually inside the displayVin() routine.  Button events send a parameter to the acion, so you should probably declare it as `-(IBAction)displayVin:(id)sender` instead of just `-(IBAction)displayVin`.

Comment: I'm inside the displayVin method, it's printing out fine, thanks for the tip . I've added (id)sender, now using - (IBAction)displayVin:(id)sender in the header and implementation file, it's now crashing ( i guess it's a good thing, at least it's registering ), log in the updated question

Answer (score 0):

For your updated code, you might have to reconnect the IBOutlet in the IB file. It looks like it's still calling the [viewController displayVin] method (without arguments), instead of the [viewController displayVin:]

Comment: nice, not crashing anymore ! thanks . It's still printing out the NSlog correctly, ok not doing anything else, like moving the view for example but at least it's not crashing :)

Comment: After reading your code again: check if you're really using a navigationController. If you're not, the self.navigationController will not be set, and the pushModalViewController won't do anything. Assuming the IBAction method is in a viewController, replacing that call with [self pushModalViewController:vinController animated:YES]; should work...

Comment: thanks for that I've replace with just "self" instead of "self.navigationController" but now it's complaining like this : "warning: 'VinsViewController' may not respond to '-pushViewController:animated:'"